# How can I select id of rows that all of rows have

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table:

```
+-------------+----------+
|stud_group_id|subject_id|
+-------------+----------+
|    1g       |   1s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    1g       |   2s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    1g       |   3s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    2g       |   1s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    2g       |   2s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    3g       |   1s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    3g       |   2s     |
+-------------+----------+
|    3g       |   4s     |
+-------------+----------+
```

I need to select `subject_id` learned by all `stud_group_id`.
I expect

```
+----------+
|subject_id|
+----------+
|   1s     |
+----------+
|   2s     |
+----------+
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output

Comment: Question is incomplete/unclear as it is see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Just `SELECT DISTINCT(subject_id) FROM your-table`

Comment: @Roy, no, there will all subject_id's. I need just these that are in every stud_group_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
select 
    subject_id,
    count(distinct stud_group_id) as cnt
from
    <your_table>
group by
    subject_id
having cnt=(select count(distinct stud_group_id) from <your table>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines:

```
select count(stud_group_id) as num_learners_from_group, subject_id 
    from your_table group by subject_id 
    having num_learners_from_group = 
      (select count(*) 
         from stud_groups_table 
         where stud_groups_table.stud_group_id = your_table.stud_group_id
         group by stud_groups_table.stud_group_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `having` clause as below :

```
select subject_id         
  from tab
 group by subject_id
having count(distinct stud_group_id) = ( select count(distinct stud_group_id) from tab )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=39fece67d7453ff68e00d83508fafec3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned a table name, so using TABLE_NAME as a placeholder.

```
select distinct subject_id from TABLE_NAME group by stud_group_id, subject_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you:

```
select subject_id
from mytable
group by subject_id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct stud_group_id) from mytable)
```